# how to print the value of a variable in airflow

Tags: airflow, google-cloud-composer

I'm trying to print the content of a variable computed in airflow dag ,therefore I used an echo in a bash operator, but It doesn't work
I tried with a predefined variable but, I got the same output
here is an example :

```
with DAG(
    dag_id="tmp",
) as dag:
test="test"
test_dag = BashOperator(
    task_id="test_dag",
    bash_command='echo $test',
)
```

the output is always empty :

> Output:
> INFO -

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass the variable in a f-string. You can even set the task_id based on your variable. See:

```py
    with DAG(
        dag_id="tmp",
    ) as dag:
        test="test"
        test_dag = BashOperator(
            task_id=f"t1_{test}",
            bash_command=f"echo {test}",
        )
```

Comment: it give : Output:
INFO - {test}

Comment: Are you using f-string? Please note the f before the string.

Comment: yess that was the issue, now it works as a charm, thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the `env` parameter like so:

```py
with DAG(dag_id="tmp", start_date=datetime(2022, 1, 1), schedule_interval=None) as dag:
    test_dag = BashOperator(
        task_id="t1",
        bash_command="echo $test",
        env={"test": "something"},
    )
```

[image]